# How to disable multiple checkbox selections in one column?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am working with the `rhandsontable` package. I would like to know if it is possible to disable multiple selection of checkboxes in a column. I want the user to select only one checkbox at a time, just like in the `dt` package. I have searched the web and the `rhandsontable` documentation, but I cannot find any information on this.

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know. I would also appreciate any resources on how to use the render function of `hot_col` in `rhandsontable`.

I was able to do this with the `dt` package but due to some constraints I have to use `rhandsontable`.